# Which grok pattern for logstash multiline with different event dividers

Tags: plone, logstash, zope, grok

I have a log file (zope/plone event.log) which using custom string (e.g "-----") as divider between events, how grok pattern for parsing this log file to logstash should be?

This is an example how the log look like:

```
------
2014-07-21T12:13:30 INFO ZServer HTTP server started at Mon Jul 21 12:13:30 2014
        Hostname: localhost
        Port: 8401
------
2014-07-21T12:13:44 WARNING SecurityInfo Conflicting security declarations for "setText"
------
2014-07-21T12:13:44 WARNING SecurityInfo Class "ATTopic" had conflicting security declarations
------
2014-07-21T12:13:47 INFO DocFinderTab Applied patch version 1.0.5.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should start with the multiline codec or filter to create a single event for processing.

EDIT:

The doc gives this example:

```
filter {
  multiline {
    pattern => "pattern, a regexp"
    negate => boolean
    what => "previous" or "next"
  }
}
```

And describes what 'negate' and 'what' do.  Hopefully 'pattern' make sense.

So, how about "every line that doesn't start with a date belongs with the prior line"?  That might be something like this:

```
filter {
  multiline {
    negate => 'true'
    pattern => "^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601} "
    what => 'previous'
  }
}
```

You'd be left with the "----" at the end of each line.  Since you don't need them as delimiters, you can get rid of them (before the multiline filter stanza):

```
if message =~ /^-+$/ {
    drop{}
}
```

Comment: I've checked the multiline filter here http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.1/filters/multiline. However there is only 1 way to specify multiline event is define the pattern of the next line or previous line. However, in my case, the event is divided by "-----" string, not the end line, so the beginning pattern of every could be vary

Comment: You can say that "everything that is not a ----- belongs to the previous line", etc.

Comment: Yes, it's true, but I'm new with grok and I dont know how to write that rule. Do you know how to do it or point me a place that I can learn how to do it? Thanks in advanced!